# How to disable the Windows swipe-away screen lock, without disabling the password?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, windows-8.1

Windows has a slide-away lock screen, as is common for mobile operating systems designed for a touch interface, to prevent accidental input. On a desktop PC, laptop without a touch screen, or laptop for which accidental touches are unlikely (like a clamshell), this is just an extra unnecessary step before logging in. The option to disable the lock screen will disable the entire lock screen, including the password requirement, which is not always desirable.

While a keypress will dismiss this screen, there is a delay after that keypress before the password box becomes editable, so you can't just type "<kbd>spacebar</kbd>[password]" to log in. The first character or so of your password may be lost depending on your typing speed.

Is there a way to disable the swipe away screen, and have Windows wake up directly to the password/login screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Windows 8 lock screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/398015/how-to-disable-windows-8-lock-screen)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question pertains only to disabling the extra "swipe to unlock" feature that is unnecessary on devices without touch. While the other only pertains to disabling the lock screen entirely (password and all). Furthermore, that question is about the old preview version of Windows 8 in which it appears the obvious options worked incorrectly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you can disable the lock screen without disabling authentication, using the **Local Group Policy Editor**. Here's how to do it:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `gpedit.msc` (runs Local Group Policy Editor)
3. Navigate to: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization
4. Enable the setting: **Do not display lock screen**

[image]

If you do not own the "Pro" version of Windows 8/8.1/10 then you do not have access to the policy editor. You can still edit the policy, but you need to go through *regedit* instead. It's only slightly more complicated that way:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `regedit` (runs Registry Editor)
3. Find the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization`

   - `Personalization` May not exist under `Windows`, so right click its label and select New > Key to create it
4. Right click on `Personalization` and select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value
5. Name the new value `NoLockScreen`
6. Now Right Click > Modify the new DWORD and enter `1` for the Data Value

Now, when you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, you'll be presented with the password input screen instead of the lock screen.

*Thanks to Xandy in the comments for this Registry edit*

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: To complete the answer, as far as I know the Core version of Windows 8 doesn't ship the policies editor. In that case users can accomplish the same by editing the registry. The corresponding entry is a `DWORD` named `NoLockScreen` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization` (if that key doesn't exist you can create it). A value of `1` would disable the lock screen. `0`, or deleting it would enable it again ;).

Comment: You can also hit the up arrow on the keyboard, it will swipe the lock screen up

Comment: @Amadeu: or `Enter`, or any alphabetical, or almost any key, really :)

Comment: I recently tried this on a computer that lacked the policy editor, the registry change did not seem to work however.

Comment: Anyone know how to put a clock on the login screen since the lock screen is now disabled?

Comment: is there really NO solution to keep the slide-away lockscreen and have the password box respond immediately? I mean, really, who tests these things nowadays?

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to no longer work in Windows 10 post-anniversary update. Neither of my laptops act any differently.

Comment: And now, two years later, it mysteriously works again! I have no idea what version of windows it changed on, but as of **1803** it is working again.

Comment: Still works in Windows 11.

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 11 just now. If you're not able to get it to work make sure you're using the US spelling of `Personalization` with a `z` and not an `s`. Also why on earth isn't this a setting that's easier to change? Windows has become a huge mess of things you have to disable.

Answer (score 1):

For the lazy people of the world this can be run with PowerShell:

```
$Key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization"
If  ( -Not ( Test-Path "Registry::$Key")){New-Item -Path "Registry::$Key" -ItemType RegistryKey -Force}
Set-ItemProperty -path "Registry::$Key" -Name "NoLockScreen" -Type "DWORD" -Value 1
```