# Monitor turning off triggering password prompt on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, display-settings, password-protection

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro on a laptop. As soon as the laptop's display turns off, the computer requires me to enter a password to log back in. **How can I prevent the display timeout from requiring a password?**

- No screen saver is configured.
- The option `On resume, display logon screen` is disabled.
- I've confirmed the PC is *not* going to sleep.

Many solutions on Google direct you to Metro PC Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options to change the `Require a password after the display is off` option ([example](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/28485-password-require-after-display-off-windows-8-1-a.html)). But I don't have that option:

[image]

I have no idea what "setting is managed by my system administrator" that's greying this option out. *(I think this clue is the key to solving my problem.)*

---

What I've tried:

- This [Microsoft forum thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/20847146-a4ff-4b88-9bab-ccc70b5d1554/do-not-require-password-after-display-off) describes my problem, but the solutions don't work.
- The registry settings from [Set Time to Require Password after Display is Off with a REG File](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/28485-password-require-after-display-off-windows-8-1-a.html) from eightforums.com.  They have no effect whatsoever.
- Reviewed [How do I prevent the Welcome Screen / Lock Screen from appearing after idling in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/472553/how-do-i-prevent-the-welcome-screen-lock-screen-from-appearing-after-idling-in)
- [This SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/496647/213131) suggests resetting the security settings in Control Panel.  I don't have this option.
- [This SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/550627/213131) suggests a Group Policy setting change. I didn't work for me because my laptop doesn't support [InstantGo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstantGo).
- Reviewed [How to delay Windows 8 lock screen](https://superuser.com/questions/501904/how-to-delay-windows-8-lock-screen)
- [This SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/532144/213131) suggests a Reg edit that exposes additional Power options including *Console lock display off timeout*. I also found the MSKB article [Monitor powers off after 1 minute when PC is locked](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835052) which refers to the same settings.  No form of them work however.
- Reviewed [How to delay the screen lock until some time after the screen turns off in Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/706237/how-do-delay-the-screen-lock-until-some-time-after-the-screen-turns-off-in-windo)
- [This SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/706278/213131) suggests enabling the `Machine Inactivity Limit` Group Policy setting. The setting works, but only to the point of deciding how quickly the PC is locked, after which a password is required.

Comment: "setting is managed by my system administrator" Is this your personal computer, or a work computer? Are you on a Domain? Have you run GPResult to determine which (if any) group policies are being applied (by your System administrator)?

Comment: PC is part of a domain. I have actually moved the PC to an OU that has no Group Policy and confirmed none are applied to the PC, but the problem persists.

Comment: Ahhh.. if you move it to an OU with no policies configured, then whatever configurations were previously set by policy will continue to be applied until you apply NEW policies that (re)set the settings back to the various defaults.

Comment: Group Policy normally [doesn't tattoo](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/373510-im-surprised-how-many-people-think-all-gps-tattoo-on-the-registry), but I'll double-check. The only screen saver or power management setting applied via GP was `Specify the System Sleep Timeout (plugged in)` which is/was set to `0` (disabled).

Comment: User _Preferences_ (which is what power options usually are) do tattoo. Basically anything that doesn't use/respect the "Policies" reg keys will tattoo. But how about this: Do other computers on the domain have the same problem?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 You are correct. The only user preferences in use are for drive mappings and printers. Still, I'll confirm nothing's slipping through the cracks and report back.

Comment: Down voter: Care to explain what's not to site standards with this question?

Answer (score 2):

"Require a password on wakeup = No" <- this is why it's not asking for a password when you wake it up from sleep.

When it JUST turns off the monitors (with no screensaver enabled, or at least don't enable "On resume, display logon screen") then it shouldn't ask for a password (mine sure doesn't ;) ).

So to sum up:

- Enable "Require a password on wakeup".
- Disable "On resume, display logon screen" for your screen saver.

Comment: As Techie007 points out.  There is a difference between the logon screen and the lock screen.  One can make it that once logged in Windows never locks itself and thus the logon screen after being locked is never displayed.

Comment: Enabling **Require a password on wakeup** does produce the desired behavior of a password being required on resume from sleep, **but it also forces a password to be required after the display turns off**. It's this latter behavior I'm trying to address.

Comment: It shouldn't, since blanking the monitors is not the same as putting it into a sleep state.  Have you confirmed it's ONLY turning off the monitors when you think that's what's happening?

Comment: Yes. I have "Put the computer to sleep" disabled for both battery and AC power sources, and I have confirmed beyond a shadow of a doubt that the machine is not going to sleep.