# Disable the Windows 8 lock screen

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable the Windows 8 lock screen, without disabling the password?](https://superuser.com/questions/497736/how-to-disable-the-windows-8-lock-screen-without-disabling-the-password)

Every time I walk away from my laptop, the screen locks. Very annoying. Is there a way to disable the lock screen? Note: I do not have gpedit.msc available.

Comment: See the comment on the other answer for use without gpedit.msc ( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization\, set DWord NoLockScreen to 1 to disable the lock screen).

Comment: @Hennes That did not work