# During periords of Inactivity in Windows 8, the computer screen locks.

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable the Windows 8 lock screen, without disabling the password?](https://superuser.com/questions/497736/how-to-disable-the-windows-8-lock-screen-without-disabling-the-password)

During periods of In-activity in Windows 8, the MS 8 locks (unlike windows 7) and you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to restore the activity.  How do I eliminate this? Power Options did not do it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Windows 8 Lock Screen?  I ask so that we can help indentify the component that you want to fix.