# Directly booting to log-in screen

Tags: windows-8.1

When I boot or wake up my laptop running Windows 8.1, it first shows me a wallpaper and displays the time.

Then I have to click or press any key in order to get to the login screen, where I can enter my password.

Is there any way to directly get to the login screen, without getting to the wallpaper screen first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable the Windows 8 lock screen, without disabling the password?](http://superuser.com/questions/497736/how-to-disable-the-windows-8-lock-screen-without-disabling-the-password)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep it can be done fairly easily although only tested on Windows 8 not 8.1...:

Click on the Start ORB key, type gpedit.msc, and press Enter.

You should now get Local Group Policy Editor open up.

Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization

Change 'Do not display the lock screen' to Enabled and then reboot Windows.

Comment: This will of course work within Windows 8.1, it also would work on Windows 7, nothing has changed with the lock screen between them.

Comment: well hidden, but very easy to accomplish. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ramhound did you mean Windows 8? There's no lockscreen in Windows 7 AFAIK.

Comment: @gronostaj - I actually meant Windows 7.  Windows 7 has a lockscreen( Ctrl+ALT+DEL screen ) or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, that's what you meant. I believe this question is dealing with that [fullscreen wallpaper and clock thing](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/customization/36425d1391329314-how-do-i-change-login-screen-image-not-lock-screen-lock-screen.jpg) that you have to slide up before you can enter your password in Windows 8[.1].

Comment: @Ramhound the Ctrl+Alt+Del is controlled by another setting called "Do not require pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del when logging in". As gronostaj pointed out, this questions deals with disabling the stupid and useless smartphone-style lockscreen introduced in Windows 8.

Comment: Its not stupid, you might not like it, but it can be disabled so no reason to call it stupid.